# UTF8 characters in Django source code

Tags: python, django, character-encoding

I have some accented characters in my Python source code (comments, strings), and Django gives me an error for those characters.

I have to put this line at the top of the Python file to make it work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Is there a way to globally allow UTF8 in the whole project?

Comment: You could upgrade to python 3, you'll need to anyway for django 2.0

Comment: Check this out `https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/GlobalState`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, source files are interpreted as ASCII by default, unless a coding declaration like the one in your question appears at the top of the file.

In Python 3, source files are interpreted as UTF-8 by default (again, unless a coding declaration specifies some other encoding).

Information on the history of this change can be found in PEP 3120: [Using UTF-8 as the default source encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/).

There's no other way to force Python to interpret a source file as an encoding other than the default.

So, you have two choices:

1. Add the coding declaration to every source file which includes non-ASCII characters.
2. Switch to Python 3.

Option 2 is by far the better choice, and will save you a lot of headache in the long run.